# Micorsoft Outlook GraphAPI Returns Nulls

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, integration, outlook-restapi

I'm working on a .NET Project, in summary I need to call the Outlook Graph API to get messages from a certain mailbox, parse the data returned and save into a database. I'm able to make the call but out of the +37 fields (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) that a messages payload returns, only 3 fields have any values in them namely (Id, Subject and sender ) all other fields are null.
I enabled the entire permission realated to messages here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions) yet, I continually get nulls also I'm logged in as admin.

Please help with pointers.

Regards

Comment: It would help if you included the request you're making i.e. the endpoint you're calling. For example Microsoft graph has a `$select` parameter that lets you choose certain columns e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=sender,subject`

Comment: yeah try the above (you need to use $select) and see if it helps.